# What Is The Real Grand GRAND Ancestor Process In The Linux Kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, userspace

While trying to find all the roots of certain process application made in C, and calls a custom system call I made that returns an array of all the process using task_struct*'s info, I experienced that the task swapper/0 is the task that points to itself through the parent pointer (i.e. swapper/0->parent == swaper/0). My question is: Which one is the real grand GRAND parent of any process running in the user space? is it swapper/0 or the task right before it (or swapper/0's child)? I.e. is swapper/0 is meant to be a real task, or just an ending flag for traversing the parent linked lists?

Btw, this question extends the question posted by me in this post: [The ending flag to traversing ancestors in the kernel space in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540595/the-ending-flag-to-traversing-ancestors-in-the-kernel-space-in-c/).

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83322/which-process-has-pid-0

Comment: Now I got that swapper/0 is part of the system using the post you gave me, but should I consider it as the root of all parents in this case?

Comment: My understanding (which may not be accurate) is that swapper/0 owns a set of kernel threads and init/1 owns the user processes.

Answer (score 4):

init (pid 1) is the process which is the ancestor of all other user processes. init is responsible for starting up all of the user-level processes that run the system. Furthermore, a process whose parent exits is inherited by init (i.e., init becomes its parent).